# Working with multiple relationship in one field on Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm having a little problem with a possible multiple relationship in one field in Doctrine 2. For example, i have an `Article` entity with one field called `author`. This field is a ManyToOne to the `User` entity. However, this field can also relate to the `Group` entity. So, how the hell can i create such schema?

I have considered creating a new entity, called `ArticleAuthor` which has two fields: `user` and `group`, and depending on form input, i populate one of the fields. This way, this table `ArticleAuthor` holds it's own `id` and the proper relationship to the correct table. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what's referred to as a polymorphic association. Doctrine is able to handle these using [Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping)

So you'd define your base entity, such as `Author`, and then you'd have a `GroupAuthor` and a `UserAuthor` which both extend this. These both need to be configured as mapped classes on the base `Author` entity. It's up to you whether you opt for single table or class table inheritance; the end result would be the same.

The last thing to do is to associate the `UserAuthor` entity to your `User` entity, and your `GroupAuthor` to your `Group` entity.

Then you'd be able to use it somewhat like this:

```
$author = $article->getAuthor();
if ($author instanceof UserAuthor) {
    $user = $author->getUser();
} elseif ($author instanceof GroupAuthor) {
    $group = $author->getGroup();
    $users = $group->getUsers(); // Not sure if you'd need this?
}
```

### Edit: Example mapping

The 'parent' entity, `Author.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"user" = "UserAuthor", "group" = "GroupAuthor"} )
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /* any other shared fields... */
}
```

Mapped entity, `UserAuthor.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_authors")
 */
class UserAuthor extends Author
{
    /* All columns unique to the UserAuthor entity... */
}
```

etc

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you, Rob.

Comment: So, Author itself is not an entity? Since it's a mapped superclass. How can Article relate to it?

Comment: Inside UserAuthor, is this correct @robmasters ? `/**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="authoredArticles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;`

Comment: Also, how do i refer the `Author` field in the `Article`? /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="authoredPosts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $author;

Comment: If you have any spare time: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18309/issue-12978075

Comment: I have made a better question here, concerning my specific usage of CTI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980748/manytoone-relationship-to-a-class-table-inheritance-entity-in-doctrine-2

Comment: @vinnylinux did you figure out how to map `Author` to `Article?`