# ManyToOne association mapping to a Class Table Inheritance entity in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an `Author` entity, which is a Class Table Inheritance containing an `AuthorUser` and an `AuthorGroup`.

```
/**
 * Author
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "AuthorUser", "group" = "AuthorGroup"})
 */
class Author {
    // ...
}
```

`AuthorUser` relates to my `User` entity and `AuthorGroup` to my `Group` entity.

```
class AuthorUser extends Author
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="?????")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}

class AuthorGroup extends Author
{
    /**
     * @var Group
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="?????")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

I have no idea how to inverse this. Anyway, the problem is that i have to add this CTI to my `Article` entity field. How can i relate using ManyToOne to this Article entity field?

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="?????????")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $author;
}
```

I'm not sure how to make this as transparent as possible. When i create a new `Article`, i need to provide either an `User` or `Group` object to the `author` field. I followed this behavior, but it doesn't seem to help. It gets even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to always have AuthorGroups, even when there's only one Author.

Otherwise, take a look at https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Rateable

You might be able to use that code to provide a similar Authored interface that can discriminate between the AuthorUser and AuthorGroup.